# How can we find another path

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, limits, derivatives

[image]

Can you help me about this question please, 
Thank you..

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: I want to show that it is not continuos at origin, then it will not be differentiable at origin. So, I aproach the origin from different paths so that it will give different limit values, ie it become not continuous, but I am not sure whether it is continuos or not at origin as well.  @RichardP

Comment: I don't know what the actual question is asking you to do. But, it is sufficient to determine the partial derivatives of this function. You will see that they do not exist at (0,0), therefore the function can not be differentiable at that point.

Answer (score 0):

You want to find a path such that
$$\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^2y}{x^3-y^2}\neq0.$$
The easiest way to do this is maybe check if there is a path where the function is constant. Let us check if it can be equal to $1$.
\begin{align*}
\frac{x^2y(x)}{x^3-y^2(x)}&=1\\
y^2(x)+x^2y(x)-x^3&=0\\
y(x)&=-\frac12x^2\pm\frac12\sqrt{x^4+4x^3}
\end{align*}
where $\sqrt{x^4+4x^3}\ge0$. Now the limit becomes
$$\lim\limits_{x\to0^+}\frac{x^2y(x)}{x^3-y^2(x)}=1.$$
Since we now have two different values for the limit, the function can not be continuous and furthermore not differentiable at $(x,y)=(0,0)$.